# img2pdf.py "no module named Image"

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hello I am running Python 2.7 64 bit on windows 7. I've found a python script online called img2pdf.py which could be very useful to me but I can't run it. I've installed the Pillow library for win64 (from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) 
and Image.py is present in "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PIL"

I've downloaded the script to a directory containing my image, and python is on my path but when I type

```
python img2pdf.py myimage.j2k
```

at the command prompt I get an error that states

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "img2pdf.py" line 18, in <module>
    import Image
ImportError: No module named Image
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Pillow library link, it is written:

> Note: use `from PIL import Image` instead of `import Image`.

But when I look to the img2pdf.py script that I've found [here](https://github.com/pedrokost/utilities/blob/master/img2pdf.py), it is written `import Image`. So I guess you have to edit your img2pdf.py as specified above.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install [Python for Windows](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-350), e.g. "python-3.5.0-amd64.exe" --> C:\Python
2. Extract the zipped archive for [img2pdf](https://gitlab.mister-muffin.de/josch/img2pdf) to C:\Python\Sources\img2pdf
3. Go to C:\Python\Scripts
4. Run `pip.exe install ..\Sources\img2pdf`
5. The package is now available from command line as "img2pdf.exe" in C:\Python\Scripts