# error No module named 'img2pdf' when executing .exe - pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, img2pdf

I'm am trying to build an .exe file with pyinstaller.
When launching the build .exe file I have the following error :

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'img2pdf'

I have already build some .exe with pyinstaller, which are working. So I guess the problem is not pyinstaller. I am also using Pycharm with a virtual environnement.

The code is working well when running on Pycharm.

With the --debug all option of pyinstaller, I can see the following lines :

> img2pdf not found in PYZ Traceback (most recent call last):   File "download_pdf.py", line 7, in    File "
>
> importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load   File "", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'img2pdf' [4812] Failed to
>   execute script download_pdf

I tried pip install img2pdf in the Terminal of pycharm (virtual environnement) and in the command prompt of my OS (windows 10).

Does anyone know what's wrong ?

Comment: I hope this helps you [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517118/img2pdf-py-no-module-named-image/18517273)

Comment: I hope this will help you
[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517118/img2pdf-py-no-module-named-image/18517273)

Answer (score 1):

I had to use the following option of pyinstaller :
--hidden-import=img2pdf

It now works.